# Counting unique text in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to count how many distinct shipping methods there are in a query (the answer is 2). I am trying to use DISTINCT but it doesn't seem to be working the way I thought it would.
[image]

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(Order.ship_method) AS CountOfship_method
FROM [Order];
```

Comment: `COUNT` gives you one result row with the number 3. With `DISTINCT` you say: Please remove duplicate rows from all these one rows (sic). Obviously there can be none, so `DISTINCT` doesn't change anything. You were looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT column)` which MS Access doesn't support (as so many, many other standard SQL features). So you are forced to make records distinct in a subquery and only then count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as CountOfship_method
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Order.ship_method FROM [Order]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this the correct answer once it lets me.